# Чем заменить паттерн singleton?

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Как работает и для чего нужен паттерн Singleton знаю.

Надоедает, что все ругают и называют его анти-паттерном, мол он нарушает концепцию ООП, что не тестируется модульным тестированием без применения "хаков" и сейчас его стараются не использовать. Окей.

А чем его можно тогда заменить, если нужно выполнять именно то, для чего и придумали Singleton? В моём случае:

- нужно просто вытаскивать из класса настройки для системы в любом месте оной
- гарантированно создавать только один объект данного класса

Или это просто наговорки, тех, кто не понимает, как и где нужно этот паттерн использовать?

Куда копать-то? В какую сторону?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл, решение простое: сделать из singletona обычный класс не нарушающий принципов ООП (в моём случае с настройками системы), а вот создавать его объект при помощи IoC-контейнера, например: "Pimple":

```
Объявление сервисов «Синглтонов»:
```

По умолчанию при каждом вызове Pimple возвращает новый объект сервиса. Если же требуется **один экземпляр на всё приложение**, всё, что вам необходимо сделать – это обернуть объявление в метод share():

```
$IoC['object_name'] = $IoC->share(function ($c) {
  return new Config($c['class_name']);
});
```

**НО, так было раньше, в версиях 1.x**, сейчас же - метод share() разработчики Pimple удалили. Хотя вам ни кто не запретит использовать старую версию 1.x, на гитхабе она есть (ссылка есть ниже).

Хоть в новых версиях (3.x) данного контейнера и нет метода share(), но всё равно лучше использовать IoC контейнер для управлениями зависимостей, чем Singleton:

```
// Регистрируем зависимости через IoC контейнер "Pimple":
$IoC = new Container();
// Объявление сервисов:
$IoC['obj_conf'] = function ($c) {
  return new Config($c['Config']);
};
```

Ссылки:

1. https://habrahabr.ru/post/199296/
2. http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/
3. https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/blob/1.1/lib/Pimple.php - версия 1.х

И ещё:

IoC-контейнеров довольно много, пользуйтесь тем, чем вам будет удобно:

- Symfony 2 — symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html
- Laravel — laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc
- Yii 2 — www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html
- https://github.com/Molajo/IoC
- https://github.com/DTVD/IoC
- https://github.com/danpecher/ioc
- https://github.com/annexus/ioc
- https://github.com/itlessons/php-ioc
- https://github.com/digitalcreations/ioc
- https://github.com/baleyko/IoC
- https://github.com/ashwanthkumar/ioc-php
- http://phemto.sourceforge.net/
- и так далее.