# Проблемы паттерна `Singleton`

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

Изучая паттерн `Singleton` столкнулся с тем ,что классическая реализация данного паттерна очень хромает в плане *потокобезопасности* и что *Lazy-реализация* будет намного предпочтительней...

**Теперь сам вопрос** : можно ли как-то совместить эти две реализации(код попытки ниже) **либо** есть ли какой-то альтернативный вариант на `с#` ,который позволит избежать танцев с бубном при использовании данного паттерна .Net разработчику.
А если есть ,то не будет ли альтернативный вариант нарушать принципов ООП **и** не будет ли так же сложно использовать модульное тестирование .

**Например**,здесь - [Замена синглтона в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491377/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD-singleton)  ,где с класса `Singleton` просто делают самый обычный класс ,**но** сам объект при надобности - создают при помощи **IoC-контейнера** . Хотелось бы узнать оптимальный вариант в даной ситуации ,спасибо.

Ну и попытка совместить Lazy Loading с потокобезопасной реализацией :

```
  public class Singleton
{

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private Singleton()
    {
        Name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

   public static Singleton GetInstance()
{
    return Nested.instance;
}

private class Nested
{
    internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
}
}
```

Comment: [сниглтоны от Джона Скита](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: [Singleton by Jon Skeet clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550935/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое , обязательно ознакомлюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация от @RusGIS правильная, новотельная еще пример потокобезопасного с msdn
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
using System;


public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

если используете различный сторонние библиотеки, то для этого, к приему в mvvm фреймворках, есть встроенные инструменты для его реализации.

к примеру MvvmCross:

```
            CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

или

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMyClass>(new MyClass);
```

можете выбирать.

Answer (score 5):

Вот реализация синглтон + Lazy+ потокобезопасность.

```
public sealed class LazySingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<LazySingleton> _instance = new Lazy<LazySingleton>(() => new LazySingleton());
    LazySingleton() {}
    public static LazySingleton Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
}
```

Данная реализация взята из книги Сергея Теплякова "Паттерны проектирования на платформе .NET."